# Add one to a list in python (as in adding one to a vector in R)

Tags: python

I start with:

```
N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
```

I want to end with:

```
N = [11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

This almost works, but it's sure a lot more complicated than R, and doesn't give a simple list:

```
import numpy as np
N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
one = np.ones((1,len(N)), int)
Nar = np.array(N)
N = Nar + one
N = N.tolist()
print(N)
```

**Output:**

```
[[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]]
```

Comment: Just do `Nar + 1`. Why have you added this complexity?

Comment: Should I not have shown what I tried?

Comment: no, you absolutely should show what you tried. I don't know why this got downvoted as it did as I'm not sure it's merited (your question shows a clear issue and what you tried, just some misunderstanding, which is the whole point). My comment was that your approach was massively over-complicated for what you're trying to do, but that's probably just a factor of coming from R and trying to find something comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for NumPy here, use a simple list comprehension:

```
result = [value + 1 for value in N]
```

Or, if you still want to use NumPy:

```
result = (np.array(N) + 1).tolist()
```

However, the latter uses more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]

Y = [i + 1 for i in N]

print(Y)
[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the list *in-place* you can use a `for` loop:

```
>>> N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
>>> for i in range(len(N)):
...     N[i] += 1
... 
>>> N
[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

If you want a *new* list, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
>>> N = [x + 1 for x in N]
>>> N
[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a 2D array (`(1, len(N))` as shape means it's a 2D array where the first dimension is of length 1) when you want to have a 1D array:

```
import numpy as np
N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
one = np.ones(len(N), dtype=int)
Nar = np.array(N)
N = Nar + one
N = N.tolist()
print(N)
# [11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

Actually you don't need the `one` array at all:

```
Nar = np.array(N)
N = Nar + 1
N = N.tolist()
print(N)
# [11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

Or you could do all these operations in one line:

```
N = (np.asarray(N) + 1).tolist()
print(N)
# [11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to add 1 to each element:

```
>>> N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
>>> N = [n + 1 for n in N]
>>> N
[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>>>N = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
>>> N2 =[]
>>> for n in N:
>>> ...    N2.append(n + 1)
>>> N = N2 
>>> N
[11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001]
```